# What are the hard rules for php code formatting?

Tags: php

I am not asking about code guide, standards and good practise. I am asking what are the hard rules.

If I do the following will it still work:

```
public 
static 
    function
(
)
{$var
=
'String'
;
}
```

Comment: there are no given rules, only code that works, bug-free. *"If I do the following will it still work:"* - have you tried it? hard to say; I didn't see a question mark anywhere.

Comment: that one wont work because its defining an anoymous methed which arent supported and constitute a syntax error but give it a function name and within a class it would be valid

Comment: You seem to be asking for a complete specification of the PHP syntax rules. That seems to be too broad for a Stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Quentin Sometimes I feel we try to look for ways to take questions away rather than answer them. OP's not asking for a complete rule set, I read question as 'will code work if it's tabbed, spaced, etc', to which the answer varies on what you're dealing with (Declarations, blocks, etc). If you're brushed up on your PHP then you could probably sum it up fairly shortly.

Comment: To me the question is pretty simple, even without a question mark, and it is not very broad. I am asking if I can place and remove breaks and spaces at will in php code. The answer seems to be yes.

Comment: [PHP Language Specification](https://github.com/php/php-langspec)

Comment: Not what I was asking. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is syntactically correct, it will run. Like in many other programming languages, the formatting has no syntactical significance, hence there are no “hard” rules.

However, if you are looking for coding style guides you should have a look at [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/). PSR-1 defines generall guidelines for code structure, while PSR-2 goes more into detail.

If you intend to share your code with others, you should definitely format your code according to PSR-2. Even if you don't want to share your code, it's worth reading that document and trying to adhere to the rules defined there.

Comment: Thanks. I am very familiar with PSR and use it normally. I am writing an obfuscator for some of my code and wanted to make sure it was OK to strip all line breaks and then use wordwrap() to not have too long lines. Seems to be the case. Code works fine, but might break in future which is why I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, in that case, you don't need to worry. All whitespace characters between [parser tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) are treated equally – no matter if tab, space or newline.

Comment: Btw, sorry for lecturing about PSR-1/2, didn't read the first sentence of your question. ;) Thanks for accepting/upvoting anyway. Hope my above comment explains the matter to your satisfaction.